# how to apply constraint by Stored procedures that ID should start with 'E' and has 2 numerics aftarwards?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure

`EID` should only be inserted if it starts with `'E'` and has 2 numerics aftarwards ....
i was trying to write a procedure for the purpose like:

```
create proc emp_checks(@eid varchar(20), @name varchar(20),@age int, @salary int, @city varchar(20))
AS
Begin
Declare @citycount int= (select count(*) from employee where @city=city)

if (@citycount < 2 and @eid like 'E--%')
insert into employee values(@eid,@name,@age,@salary,@city)
else 
print 'city exceeded'
End
```

here the issue is that `--` or spaces would insert non-numerics also
here this code also includes few extras *just homework things :)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you write a stored procedure?  MySQL now supports `check` constraints:

```
alter table employee add constraint chk_employee_eid
    check (eid regexp '^E[0-9]{2}')
```

Note that this allows anything after the first 3 characters.  If you don't want anything, then add `$` to the pattern:

```
alter table employee add constraint chk_employee_eid
    check (eid regexp '^E[0-9]{2}$')
```